# Targeted string replace in csv file php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file as follows

```
Head1,Head2,Head3
a,b,c
X1,c,X1
```

based on the array input, I have to replace the value of X1 to A1. So If array inputs [2,2], the output should be

```
Head1,Head2,Head3
a,b,c
X1,c,A1
```

and if array inputs [2,0] my output should be

```
Head1,Head2,Head3
a,b,c
A1,c,X1
```

I am replacing X1's with A1 using str_replace but how to I do targeted string replace.

```
$path_to_file = dirname(__DIR__)."/abc.csv";
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("X1","A1",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your right, but your array is defining the row and column where you want to replace `X1` with `A1`? If yes do you want to replace everything there with `A1` or only if it is `X1`?

Comment: @Rizier123 Good point. For now, anything with A1. I can do the validation myself..

Comment: But your array is defining the row and column, where you want to replace the value? (excluding the header)

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, for sake of argument, I would like to replace (whatever value is in [2,2] (in this case X1) with A1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and then use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) on each line/element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). So with this you can access each value with `$file[row][column]` and change the value if you want.

To save it back you can just open the file and put the data back with [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Code:

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines = array_map("str_getcsv", $lines);

    $input = ["row" => 2, "column" => 0];
    $lines[$input["row"]][$input["column"]] = "A1";


    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($lines as $line)
        fputcsv($fp, $line);

    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: what are you doing here:   $input = ["row" => 2, "column" => 0];?? why >=

Comment: @Ank To show how you can use your input array to change the value which you want.

Comment: and why FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES

Comment: @Ank As the constants already say, the first one is that you don't have the new line characters at the end of each line, just in case if you compare it you don't get unexpected behaviour. And the second one is that you ignore new lines in your file, because you probably don't want to take them into account.

Comment: What a god send, this helped me so much!